# Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb K$ and $v\in V$. Show that if $f(v) = 0$, for all $f \in V^*$ , then $v = 0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, proof-writing, linear-transformations

> Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb K$ and $v \in V$. Show that if $f(v) = 0$, for all $f \in V^*$ , then $v = 0$.

That's what I managed to do.

Let $\cal{B}=(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n)$ be a base of $V$, and $\cal{B}^*=(\alpha_1^*,...,\alpha_n^*)$ be  dual base of $V^∗$.

Then  $b_i^*(v)=0$ for all $i=1,...,n$ and  by definition of the dual base we have
$\alpha_i^*(v)=\alpha_i^*(\sum_{j=1}^n c_j\alpha_j) = \sum_{j=1}^n c_j \alpha_i^*(\alpha_j)=\sum_{j=1}^n c_j \delta_{ij} = c_i =0, i=1,...,n$

so $v = 0⋅\alpha_1 +...+ 0⋅\alpha_n = 0 \in V$

Did I manage to prove it properly?

Comment: your proof is correct provided the $V$ is finite dimensioanl(which seems to be the case)

Comment: So you should add "finite-dimensional" in the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, if $v$ is a non-zero vector of $V$, then you can complete the set $\{v\}$, which is certainly linearly independent, to a basis $\{v,v_2,\dots,v_n\}$ of $V$, and use the latter to construct a linear map $\phi:V\to k$ such that $\phi(v)=1$ and $\phi(v_i)=0$ for all $i\in\{2,\dots,n\}$. This is an element of $V^*$ which does not vanish on $v$.

This is the contrapositive of your claim.

Answer (score 0):

For $V$ a normed vector space (or $E$ in the picture below)  over $K=\mathbb{R}$ with norm $\vert\vert\cdot\vert\vert$, I suggest you use Corollary 1.3:

[image: Screenshot of part of page 3, Brezis' book on Functional Analysis]

The image above is a screenshot of part of page 3, Brezis' book on Functional Analysis.

Comment: The question does not involve vector spaces with norms.

Comment: Specifically, there is no indication that $\Bbb K=\Bbb R\lor \Bbb K=\Bbb C$.

Comment: True! Editing comment above

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez There is no circularity, because you need only use the fact that the map that sends the linear maps in $T\in(E^\star,\lVert \cdot\rVert_\star)$ to their restriction to the closed unit ball $\left.T\right\rvert_{\bar B(E)}\in CB(\bar B(E),\Bbb R,\lVert \cdot\rVert_\infty)$ (where $\lVert f\rVert_\infty=\sup_{x\in \bar B(E)} \lvert f(x)\rvert$) is an isometry onto a closed subspace (uniform limit of restrictions of linear maps is the restriction of a linear map).

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Once you have that, you can extend the result to $E^\star$ being Banach even if $E$ is not Banach by embedding densely $E$ into its completion. More generally, with the same ideas you can say that $L(E,V)$ with the operator norm is Banach for all $V$ Banach and $E$ normed.